# Postgres set work_mem is not reflecting in session

Tags: postgresql

My Postgres version is 9.6 ("PostgreSQL 9.6.16 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23), 64-bit"). I am trying to set the work_mem value for a session but it is not reflecting value. In a query window, I am doing following

```
show work_mem --displays "2MB"
SET work_mem = '256MB'; --displays "Query returned successfully with no result in 32 msec." in output pane
show work_mem --displays "2MB" again
```

The set command is successfully executed but value is not changed. please suggest something.

Comment: Looks like there is a connection pool in between, and the `SHOW` is running in a different database session than the `SET`.

Comment: I am executing commands from pgadmin3 query tools.

Comment: Then perhaps you are running the statements in different query tool windows. Or there is a basic mistake and you execute something else than you think you do. At any rate, that can never happen in a single session in standard PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

It will work for single request:

```
SET work_mem = '256MB';show work_mem;
```

to make it available for the session you should update it on session level ( can't remember request )
to make it available for all next sessions:

```
ALTER USER <username> SET work_mem TO '256MB';
```